# Is there any way to display radio button dynamically in nested JSON in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am trying to create a question-answer HTML form with angular 6. In that, I have a nested JSON

**My JSON:**

```
questionDetail = [
        {"question":"test1","answer":["1","2","3"]},
        {"question":"test2","answer":["4","5"]}
    ]
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let q of questionDetail; let i = index">
        <div><h5>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</h5>
         <div *ngFor="let a of q.answer">
             <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected" [value]="a">&nbsp;{{a}}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

If i try to select 2nd question's answer the 1st question's answer went unselected like this

[image]

How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio button group is wrong, it is creating the same name for all the inputs

You need to differentiate between 2 questions.

```
<div *ngFor="let q of questionDetail; let i = index">
        <div><h5>{{i + 1}}. {{q.question}}</h5>
         <div *ngFor="let a of q.answer">
             <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected[i]" name="{{i}}" [value]="a">&nbsp;{{a}}

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Like this: `[(ngModel)]="radioSelected[i]" name="{{i}}"` note this 2 changes, applied to differentiate the groups, we will have question 1 value in radioselect[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aujazb) and radioselect[2] for question2.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aujazb)